# js, алгоритм работы с сеткой (получение всех элементов окружающих заданных элемент.)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Суть задачи такова: дана сетка NxN (блоки div ), если мы кликаем на ячейку в ней появляется "5", а ячейки вокруг неё заполняются "4". Собственно интересует способ получить все окружающие элементы.
 генерируется "таблица" (в данном случае 5 на 5)

```
function createTable(n) {
    var table = document.createElement('div');
    table.id = 'table';

    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        for(var j = 0; j< n; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.className = 'cell';
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    var doc = document.getElementById('root');
    doc.appendChild(table);
    console.log('createTable');
}
```

при клике на ячейку - получиться должно вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и в чем проблема? позиция ячейки известна, вокруг нее 8 ячеек позиция которых так же известна

Comment: вешай обработчик на контейнер с ячейками, затем отслеживай на какую кликаешь и выводи 5, остальным 4. Ничего сложного.

Comment: а почему именно 5 в кликнутой ячейке и 4 в соседних ? мне одному это кажется странным ?

Comment: @ampawd, да, тебе одному :-)

Comment: @Grundy, как раз позиции тех 8-ми ячеек и нужны, только как эту "коллекцию" получить ...?(

Comment: @AlexeyAntonovich, добавь в вопрос, что у тебя есть сейчас, код/разметка, и что нужно получить

Comment: Игру делаете?))

Comment: @Grundy пускай даже не имеет значения что там и как в ячейках, задача тривиальная )) (набросал код в ответе)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(x = max(0, i - 1); x <= min(n, i + 1); x++){
    for(y = max(0, j - 1); y <= min(m, j + 1); y++){
        if(x == i && y == j) continue; //Собственно, точка на которую кликнули

        //Делаем необходимое с точками вокруг


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот как вариант можно так, и тут важно заметить, что массив ячеек нужно сделать двумерным для удобного нахождения соседей по `x` и `y` текущей кликнутой ячейки.

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');
var cellDivs = {};
var n = 5; 
var cellSize = 40;
var table;
function createTable(n, cellSize) {
    var table = document.createElement('div');  table.id = 'table';
    var left = 0, top = 0, cell;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) { cellDivs[i*cellSize] = {}; }
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {     
        for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.className = 'cell';
            cell.style.width = cellSize + "px";
            cell.style.height = cellSize + "px";
            cell.style.left = left + "px";
            cell.style.top = top + "px";
            table.appendChild(cell);
            cellDivs[left][top] = cell;
            left += cellSize;          
        }
        top += cellSize; left = 0;
    }
    root.appendChild(table);
    return table;
}

table = createTable(n, cellSize);
table.onclick = function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  var x = parseInt(e.target.style.left);
  var y = parseInt(e.target.style.top);
  
  setCellValue( x,            y,            5 );
  setCellValue( x + cellSize, y + cellSize, 4 );
  setCellValue( x - cellSize, y - cellSize, 4 );
  setCellValue( x + cellSize, y - cellSize, 4 );
  setCellValue( x - cellSize, y + cellSize, 4 );
  setCellValue( x + cellSize, y,            4 );
  setCellValue( x - cellSize, y,            4 );
  setCellValue( x,            y + cellSize, 4 );
  setCellValue( x,            y - cellSize, 4 );
}

function setCellValue(x, y, val) {
  if (cellDivs[x] && cellDivs[x][y]) {
    cellDivs[x][y].innerHTML = val;
  }
}
```

```css
.cell { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ведь не выпендриваться и просто написать в лоб (es6)

```
function getNeighbors({x, y}) {
    const neighobrs = [];
    /**
    *    Начинаем с левого верхнего угла
    */
    neighobrs.push({x: x-1, y: y-1});
    neighobrs.push({x, y: y-1});
    neighobrs.push({x: x+1, y: y-1});

    neighobrs.push({x: x-1, y});
    neighobrs.push({x: x+1, y});

    neighobrs.push({x: x-1, y: y+1});
    neighobrs.push({x, y: y+1});
    neighobrs.push({x: x+1, y: y+1});

    return neighobrs;
}
```

Comment: `div` ы могут быть не единичного размера, да и не понятно как это применить к задаче, как хранить массив ячеек ?

Comment: а где в коде es6? одно слово _const_? В данном случае никакой разницы нет, что использовать для определения переменной _const_, _let_, или _var_

Comment: @Grundy, упрощенное объявление объектов + параметры функции, не обратили внимание?

Comment: @ThisMan, неа, не обратил, да и выгоды от этого, по крайней мере в данном куске не много

Answer (score 0):

Записываем все ячейки в массив. При клике на ячейку по номерам находим элементы.

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
function createTable(n) {
    var table = document.createElement('div');
    table.id = 'table';

    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        for(var j = 0; j< n; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.className = 'cell';
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    var doc = document.getElementById('root');
    doc.appendChild(table);
    console.log('createTable');

    var divs = table.querySelectorAll(".cell");
    divs.forEach(function(el, iNum){
        el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            this.innerText = 5;

            divs[iNum-1].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum+1].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum-n].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum-n-1].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum-n+1].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum+n].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum+n-1].innerText = 4;
            divs[iNum+n+1].innerText = 4;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: у вас как то маловато ячеек

Comment: Поправил код добавил все ячейки

Comment: как ни странно, но: `var table = document.createElement('div');` создает **пустой** див, поэтому следующий вызов `var divs = table.querySelectorAll("div");` вернет пустую коллекцию. Отдельно стоит отметить, что метод `forEach` добавлен в эту коллекцию **только** в хроме, и в остальных браузерах будет просто ошибка в консоли

Comment: в обновленном коде тоже ошибка `table.querySelectorAll("div")` вернет **все** дивы внутри дива _table_, включая дивы-строки, а нужны только дивы-ячейки

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. Поправил — в первую очередь показывал как реализовать алгоритм работы.

Comment: @Mihanik71, на самом деле мог бы просто заменить ту строку на _createTable()_ - Типа какая-то функция которая создает и возвращает, либо вообще ту часть убрать и оставить только перебор дивов.

Comment: @Grundy я объявил переменные что бы видно было что там и что бы видно было откуда они) Спасибо внимательнее буду

Comment: @Mihanik71, вот поэтому и обратил внимание, что в том виде как было как раз это и не понятно было :)